# Expandable rows on material table are not working after sorting

Tags: angular, angular-material

Based on the samples in [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) I added expandable rows and sorting to my table. Each feature works like a charm for itself. But when I try to **expand a row after the table was sorted**, the first click seems to do nothing at all. The second click opens the row and instantly closes it again. When I click the same row again, it behaves normally again.

Here's a simplified version on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnqztk

As far as I could find out with logging, the `expandedElement` property is set correctly for each click, no matter if the table was sorted or not. So I guess there's somthing wrong with the animations trigger `detailExpand`. I just cannot figure out why it's not getting triggered, when `expandedElement` is set after the table is sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stumbled over [this](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13431) github issue, which indirectly solves my problem. Instead of the animation used in on the Angular Material page, use the following:

```
animations: [
    trigger('expandDetail', [
      state('collapsed, void', style({ height: '0px' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
      transition('expanded <=> void', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)'))
    ])
```

That's it. Problem solved.